# Testing abstract classes in Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

In my Ruby library I have some classes that are intended to be used through inheritance. Therefore the first thing I do in my spec file is defining a custom `Foo` class:

```
module MyGem
  describe MyClass do
    class FooMyClass < MyClass
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that the defined class will leak to other tests and must be careful using unique names or removing the class with an `after :all` block.

This feels a little bit manual considering all the magic already given by Rspec. Is there a better way to define specs for abstract classes? Mostly I want an easy way to clean the namespace of all temporal declarations.

It is specially annoying to clean up when I define multiple classes like this:

```
module MyGem
  describe MyClass do
     ... 
  end

  class FooMyClass < MyClass
    ...
  end
  describe FooMyClass do
    ...
  end
end
```

This is even harder to properly un-define with `after :all` or `after :each` blocks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One possibility is to use [anonymous classes](http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/02/ruby-creating-anonymous-classes.html).

```
  let(:fooMyClass) do
    Class.new(MyClass) do
      # ...
    end
  end
```

This way there is no need to do clean up.

Answer (score 3):

```
describe MyClass do
  let(:klass) { Class.new(MyClass) }
  it "works without assigning a constant name" do
    obj = klass.new
    expect(obj).to be_kind_of(MyClass)
  end
end
```

Creating constants in a test is always going to be painful, this is a useful workaround I've used.

Answer (score 0):

Following from @hjing's answer, one can also use `stub_const`

```
before do
  stub_const('MyClass', fooMyClass)
end
```

which makes `MyClass` available as a constant in your specs.  This is useful if the behaviour of the class depends on its name (as is sometimes done in fancy metaprogramming).