# Ruby on Rails - Write Rspec tests for an abstract class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, activerecord

I'm working on a project that has required me to update the typical functionality of `ApplicationRecord` to include a validation to check that every model included in the DB has a particular field. I've set this up in the following way:

```
class MyCustomApplicationRecordClass < ApplicationRecord
    self.abstract_class = true
    validate :custom_validation


    def custom_validation
        ...
    end
end
```

My models then inherit from this class in the following way:

```
class MyModel < MyCustomApplicationRecordClass
...
end
```

While the validation works as anticipated & I can write tests confirming the functionality is working for each of the classes that inherit from `MyCustomApplicationRecordClass`, I'm struggling with how to write tests confirming that the validation on this class is behaving as anticipated. I've tried creating a "test" class, but receive an error that my test class doesn't correspond to a table in my db (which of course it doesn't'). What's the best way to test that this validation is performing as anticipated?

Comment: Can you call `.valid?` on your test class (and check errors afterwards), without actually trying to write it to the db?

Comment: Create a "test" class that includes `ActiveModel::Model`.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer provides an option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35373590). If you create a TestClass that loads the abstract class, you can turn off the schema loading, and that will squelch the error messages, allowing you to test the abstract class.

```
class TestClass < MyCustomApplicationRecordClass
    def self.load_schema!
         @columns_hash = {}
    end
end
```